# Mortgage Company did not discharge lien when loan was refinanced - New Jersey Mercer County

Tags: united-states, mortgage, new-jersey

I am in desperate need of some help having exhausted my options

I had refinanced my home loan in 2012 through Amerisave mortgage company and as part of the refinance Amerisave paid off CitiMortgage - the previous mortgage company.

In the process of selling my house - we came to know that Citi, although got the payment from refinance never discharged the lien in the county records (Mercer county) and the buyers title search showed a lien from 2010 when the original loan was issued.

We are now stuck and cannot close. I found the contact info of the title company that closed the 2012 loan and they were helpful enough to locate the documents and send me the final HUD statement that the payment to CitiMortgage was made and that everything was in order, CitiMortgage however stopped existing as a separate company(merged with Citi bank) and all they have is an email address to request service for old accounts. I am exhausted running around with no avenue for help.

Is there any way under NJ law I can take the records I have retrieved and approach the county/state records to clear this lien of my property.

This has gotten a pretty desperate situation for me to have two mortgages and not close on my older home

Comment: You might need to speak to a real estate attorney.

Comment: Does Amerisave have a lien on your home too? (Because they shouldn't have been able to get one...)

Comment: We have been working with our attorney and the buyers title company. We were able to get all the loan closing docs from the title company that helped close the refinance in 2012 and which prove that Citimortgage loan was pain off. They dropped the ball in discharging the loan at the county records office. Now it really depends on the buyer title company if they are ok with it or not.

Comment: @TTT -- an existing lien doesn't prevent adding another.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah, I worded that poorly. They shouldn't have been able to get another first mortgage. Perhaps they can write the lien however they want but it wouldn't be first in line in a default, and that makes me wonder if Amerisave has some incentive to take care of fixing this.

Comment: @TTT — good point. It’s certainly in Amerisave’s interest to be clearly first in line if things go south. Fixing it now will certainly be easier than fixing it twenty or thirty years from now.

Answer (score 2):

This press release names two companies that took over Citimortgage's servicing business. You could try calling them: Cenlar FSB and New Residential Mortgage LLC. Could also call Citibank.

https://www.citigroup.com/citi/news/2017/170130a.htm